# Как выполнить поиск совпадений в шести столбцах?

Tags: excel

Имеется шесть столбцов с данными, каждый столбец представляет числовой ряд, нужна формула, выявляющая те числа, которые находятся во всех шести столбцах. Ключевое слово ШЕСТЬ столбцов, а не два, как везде пишется, т.е. если в пяти столбцах есть число 12, а в шестом его уже нет, то результатом должно явится сообщение типа "Н/Д" или "нет совпадений" или еще что-нибудь в этом духе.

**Обновление**

Решение формулой. На входе имеем ШЕСТЬ столбцов (довольно большие, в каждом по 370 чисел), в каждом столбце стандартный числовой ряд, т.е. ОДНИ И ТЕ ЖЕ числа, просто перемешаны они в разных столбцах по-разному, причем столбцы идут не один за другим, а между ними есть другие промежуточные столбцы. Что нужно получить на выходе: найти первые восемь совпадений. Под словом "первые" я имею в виду верхние, т.е. искать надо начинать сверху.

**Обновление**

Все, ребят, спасибо. Кому интересно, задачу удалось реализовать с помощью формулы:

```
=(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($E$3:E3;B3)>0)*(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($H$3:H3;B3)>0)*(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($K$3:K3;B3)>0)*(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($N$3:N3;B3)>0)*(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($Q$3:Q3;B3)>0)
```

А потом уже тянучкой тянуть вниз.
Адьос!

Comment: Уточните: выявить заданное число или все, которые повторяются во всех столбцах?

Comment: Решение формулой. На входе имеем ШЕСТЬ столбцов (довольно большие, в каждом по 370 чисел) в каждом столбце стандартный числовой ряд т.е. ОДНИ И ТЕ ЖЕ числа, просто перемешаны они в разных столбцах по разному, причем столбцы идут не один за другим, а между ними есть другие промежуточные столбцы. Что нужно получить на выходе: найти первые восемь совпадений. Под словом первые я имею ввиду верхние т.е. искать надо начинать сверху

Comment: После обновления задача изменилась, тебует другого, не такого простого подхода. Лучше написать функцию пользователя (UDF).
Публикация решения в теме смысла не имеет, т.к. оно связано с размещением данных в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока нет ответа на комментарий.

Формула, определяющая количество столбцов, в которых записано искомое значение (например, 99):

```
=СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(ЕСЛИ(A1:F10=99;СТОЛБЕЦ(A:F));{1;2;3;4;5}))
```

Формула массива, вводится сочетанием клавиш *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* (при этом формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками)

Т.к. количество столбцов фиксированное, можно массив, создаваемый функцей *СТОЛБЕЦ*, заменить на массив констант.

Искомое значение можно задавать в ячейке. В этом случае в формулу вписать ссылку на ячейку.

Можно определить количество столбцов для кадого значения, которые записаны в диапазон ячеек. Для этого в формуле необходимо закрепить ссылки.

Вид формулы с учетом этих пожеланий:

=СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(ЕСЛИ($A$1:$F$10=G2;{1;2;3;4;5;6});{1;2;3;4;5}))

Где *G2* - ссылка на ячейку с искомым значением.

Для того,  чтобы узнать, находится ли искомое во всех шести столбцах, достаточно проверить количество:

```
=СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(ЕСЛИ($A$1:$F$10=G2;{1;2;3;4;5;6});{1;2;3;4;5}))=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Если число столбцов меняться не будет, то прямо в лоб: =И(B1=A1;C1=A1;D1=A1) и так далее.
Вернет "Истина", если все значения совпадают.

Comment: Zufir, подразумевается поиск в массиве каждого столбца, не в одной строке.
Для одной строки достаточно

=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A1:F1;A1)=6